# Do I have to transfer gwc-layers from my GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR directory to a production server

Tags: geoserver, server, geowebcache

I am working with Geoserver and I know that it is possible to transfer the contents to the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR between servers. I have already moved my GEOWEBCACHE_CACHE_DIR to a different location so that the tiles are not transferred. I am using the embedded geowebcache in Geosserver version 2.2.5.

I however have a number of xml files in GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR/gwc-layers:

```
LayerGroupInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fab.xml
LayerGroupInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fac.xml
LayerGroupInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fad.xml
LayerInfoImpl-18e1ce0d_13ef93f68ce_-7ffd.xml
LayerInfoImpl-1c3a926c_13ef90929b2_-7a75.xml
LayerInfoImpl-2fbcd275_13e632965e7_-7feb.xml
LayerInfoImpl--4a9eec43_132d48aac79_-7fff.xml
LayerInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fae.xml
LayerInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fb0.xml
LayerInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fb4.xml
LayerInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fb6.xml
LayerInfoImpl--570ae188_124761b8d78_-7fb8.xml
```

So my question is - are these files generated automatically if I tranfer the contents of GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR or do I have to include them in the transfer?

Comment: I have solved this empirically. Yes you do need to transfer these.